# Steps to take to narrow down CSRF issue in django for one specific customer

Tags: django, csrf

I have a moderately sized website that is used successfully by 100+ people a day (not just visitors but actual interactions with forms). One user in particular is having csrf issues and I'm at a loss for what could be causing it especially since no one else seems to be having problems. I have already recommended trying out different browsers and they have tried both chrome and internet explorer to no avail. What would be the best next step to try and isolate this issue?

Current usage is in the form

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add-question" class="add-question">
        {% csrf_token %}
....
</form>
```

and of course in the middleware and requestcontext

EDIT: Specifically this user is saying that he is receiving the message: 
"'CSRF verification failed.Request aborted'"

Comment: How do you use csrf in your forms, by using template tag or by passing it manually? Do you log errors, is csrf missing or what's the issue?

Comment: We have had similar issues in our projects, and could fix them by using the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator on the respective views without ever fully grasping why the csrf cookie occasionally wasn't set properly with the tag.

Comment: Make sure they haven't bookmarked the page with a session id or something similar. Ask them to reload the page without using the cache (ctrl _ shift + r on firefox or chome).

Comment: @wobbily_col They've tried it across multiple browsers